# Hibernate says invalid identifier even if column is available in db

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I am using hibernate 4.0 as orm for one of my project...
When i am trying to do a `session.get( Table.class, 1 )` I am getting the following error...

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "TABLETYPE0_"."TTPNAME": invalid identifier
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
... 24 more
```

**Hibernate:**

```
select
    tabletype0_.ttp_id as ttp_id1_8_,
    tabletype0_.ttp_delete_fl as ttp_delete_fl2_8_,
    tabletype0_.ptn_id as ptn_id3_8_,
    tabletype0_.ttpCreatedDttm as ttpCreatedDttm4_8_,
    tabletype0_.ttpName as ttpName5_8_,
    tabletype0_.ttpVersion as ttpVersion6_8_ 
from
    table_type tabletype0_ 
where
    tabletype0_.ttpName='system'
```

My hibernate has annotation mapping as follows...

```
@javax.persistence.Basic
@javax.persistence.Column( 
    name = "ttp_name", 
    nullable = true, 
    insertable = true, 
    updatable = true )
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type( 
    type = "org.custom.hibernate.types.StringType" )
@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty
@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length( max = 255 )
private String ttpName;


public String getTtpName() 
{ 
    return this.ttpName; 
}


public void setTtpName( String val ) 
{
    this.ttpName = val; 
}
```

I dont know what mistake I am doing... Since I have the column name in the db as ttp_name, hibernate tries to query with the identifier ttpName... Please could some body help me in this...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you please add the table's ddl (create statement) to you question.

Comment: You `@Column( name = "ttp_name",...)` name has an underscore. Why don't we see it in the select.

Comment: HI hannes, Thanks for the reponse... 
  CREATE TABLE "TABLE_TYPE" 
   ( "TTP_ID" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "TTP_NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "TTP_CREATED_DTTM" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT to_date('01-JAN-2000') NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "TTP_DELETE_FL" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "TTP_VERSION" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "PTN_ID" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE
   )

Comment: Did you add the `@Table` annotation to the class?

Comment: Yes I have added.... This is how it looks...@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table( name = "table_type" )
@org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDefs( { @org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef( name = "partitionFilter" , parameters={ @org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef(name="ptn_id", type="java.lang.Integer") } ), @org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef( name = "deletedFilter" , parameters={ @org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef(name="delete_fl", type="java.lang.Boolean") } )} )

public class TableType extends AbstractHibernateObject implements Serializable